# While starting the play server config locations must not be null exception?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

While starting the play server, we are getting the exception "config locations must not be null", Can anyone let me know what's going wrong?

**Exception**

```
  Starting gpp-web at port 9000...                                      ERROR
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Config locations must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(Assert.java:241)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.setConfigLocations(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:77)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at Global.onStart(Global.java:15)
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:18)
        at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:203)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
        at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

Comment: We are using play 2.2.1.... just add in information

Comment: The exception is coming from your Global.onStart method, not from Play.  You should post the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks James,

But found the problem, actually we build three different configuration file for play depend on environment like dev, UAT & Prod.

I forgot to add the "spring.context.location="applicationContext.xml" the parameter in configuration file & error has been popping up.

But thanks for suggestion  .....

Gladiator